# React Native App:proccesReleaseResources failed

Tags: react-native

Buenas noches tengo un problema con un proyecto en React-native,

Veran por alguna razon al correr el proyecto en Genymotion Funciona perfectamente,
Pero cuando executo `cd android && gradlew assmbleRelease`, me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los paquetes que he utilizado hasta ahora.
npm react-native-vector-icons
npm -i react-native-router-flux

Anexo el link con los archivos, ya que si no se haría muy extensa la publicación 
[LINK](http://www.mediafire.com/file/jdmo41n8k62sial/TopArtist.rar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenos días después de navegar toda la noche encontré la solución.

Este error se presenta en el Android Studio 3.x en la seccion de sdk Tool 26.0.2

Al aplicar esta configuración (En mi caso), lanza el error que se describe en la publicación

Para solucionarlo hay que añadir en el archivo gradle.properties(app) la siguiente linea `android.enableAapt2=false`

De tal manera que el archivo quedara de la siguiente Manera

```
TOPARTIST_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=topartist.keystore
TOPARTIST_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-alias     
TOPARTIST_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=123456789
TOPARTIST_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=123456789

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableAapt2=false
```